# Print and display white spaces as characters

Tags: ruby

I've failed to work out how I can print and display white space characters as something that I can actually 'see'.  So for example,

```
x = "123\n"
print x
```

I'd like the output to be

```
123\n
```

rather than

```
123
.
```

The above '.' represents the new line created by '\n'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = "abc\ndef"

p s
# >> "abc\ndef"

# it's equivalent to
puts s.inspect 
# >> "abc\ndef"
```

Comment: But as far as I understood it, the OP mentioned "whitespace charecters" in general. That would require actually replacing them with something visible and printing it on the screen. Or is there any ready-made solution for this?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: well, they'll be printed in their ascii-escaped form. That makes them pretty visible, doesn't it? :)

Comment: Well, sorry for being a noob, but would it work also for example with thin space, or no-break space characters and such? I wanted to try it (`"see here: 7 µM . s⁻¹"`), but I just cannot see whether the thinspace characters I typed around `.` and nobreak space after `7` made it to this monotype font here :-). Anyway, would it work also with these? They do not have escape codes in Ruby, do they?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky: how do you type those?

Comment: Micro sign, superscripts - compose key. Thin space and nbsp, I admit I went to charmap. But had I typed them eg in LibreOffice Writer, I could have pressed Ctrl+Space or Ctrl+Shif+Space to typed them. It's thinspace and nbsp that immediately struck my mind as a problem when I read about 'whitespace characters', not tabs and linefeeds.

Comment: Well, I think I won't be too far from truth when I say that usually when programmers say "whitespace" they mean space, tab and linefeed :) Still, all those thin spaces and other special chars are certainly unicode-escapable and that's how they'll be printed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
x = "123\n"
p x
#=> "123\n"
```

This method is documented in the [Kernel module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-p).

Answer (score -2):

```
irb(main):003:0> x='123\n'
=> "123\\n"
irb(main):004:0> puts x
123\n
```

Works for me. Single quoted strings are unescaped, whilst double quoted strings are. To illustrate the difference, I've put the double quoted version below as well:

```
irb(main):001:0> x="123\n"
=> "123\n"
irb(main):002:0> puts x
123
=> nil
```

Comment: Well, in your string there's no linefeed character. This is different.

Comment: Your second string does contain a linefeed character. Now, how do you print it?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev BOTH my strings contain a linefeed character.